# True 5V CPLD other than PIC/Altera ATF150*?

Tags: ttl, 5v, programmable-logic

Are there any True 5V CPLD's families still in manufacturing other than PIC/Atmel ATF150*?

I am talking not just "5V tolerant IO", but rather ones with 5V VCCIO, able to drive 5V loads without external pull-ups. I've heard Chinese are joining FPGA/CPLD race, maybe there is a chance?

Comment: VTC - Questions seeking recommendations for specific parts are off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelKaras You raise a valid point. Although I hope it could stay as I  am not asking for a specific part. Update: Added "families" word to the text to make it more clear.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - I think this is a reasonable exemption of the rule for part recommendations: the reasoning behind the rule is that usually such questions will produce a long list of possible answers that changes frequently, but this very specific question only has a handful of possible answers and it seems unlikely that any manufactures will produce new parts of this kind in the future, as there is very little demand in comparison to 3.3V parts.  Virtually the only reason you'd wanted a 5V CPLD today is for interfacing with other obsolete parts...

Comment: Xilinx CPLD XC9572-15 ???

Comment: @AliChen [Discontinued in 2011.](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/customer_notices/xcn11010.pdf) The XC9500**XL** line is still available, but it's a 3.3V part with 5V tolerant inputs.

Comment: "...able to drive 5V loads without external pull-ups" - what exactly do you mean by '5V loads'? Most 5V CPLDs (and the GALs and PALs that were used before them) only output ~3.3V. That's fine for interfacing to 5V TTL and HCT logic.

Comment: @BruceAbbott These GALs, PALs and most of CPLD had only 1 VCC voltage, for everything (core AND IO). There is no possibility for them to output 3.3V when they are powered from 5V. That is exactly what I am interested in - able to drive 5V at some decent drive strength (10-20mA) with sharp (<5ns) fronts.

Comment: "I am interested in... drive 5V at some decent drive strength (10-20mA)" - unfortunately you might not get that with a '5V' CPLD. The XC9500 series for example only pulls up to ~4V and sources 4mA (min) at 2.4V - good for TTL but needs pullups for high speed CMOS.

Comment: Depending on your application you might be able to make use of Cypress PSoC parts as (slow) CPLDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ispMACH4A5 family from Lattice Semiconductor. For example: M4A5-32/32-10JNC. These parts are JTAG programmable and range from 32 to 256 macrocells. Plenty of stock on DigiKey, not sure about production. I used them in many designs in the 90s and early 2000s.

Answer (score 4):

Another choice from Lattice is the ispLSI 2000E series.  The parts are shown below.  You can [check availability at FindChips](https://www.findchips.com/search/isplsi).  Many/most of the 5V CPLD parts are not recommended for new designs.

A better solution might be to use logic level translators.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Silego (now dialog) Greenpack are logic + some useful analog functions

https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/configurable-mixed-signal
https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/products/slg46826

You can get them on a dip20 breakout board now, making life easier.

Answer (score 2):

True 5 V CPLDs are manufactured by Microchip after the acquisition of Atmel CPLD product line. Specifically these PLDs can also replace the Altera (Intel) EPM7000/3000 family.
ATF15xx CPLDs are recommended for new designs